# How to change a particular package import reference in every class in a project

Tags: java, eclipse, import, reference, package

Suppose I have a Java package in Eclipse with 50 classes. This package is called `PackageA`. Suppose further a package called `PackageB` with the class `ClassName` that I want to import into all 50 classes within `PackageA`.

Currently I do this by doing `import somefolder.ClassName` within all 50 classes in `PackageA`, after placing `PackageB` onto my build path (here, `ClassName` is within folder `somefolder` within `PackageB`).

Suppose that `ProjectB` is deprecated in favour of `ProjectC`, and that I want to replace all `import somefolder.ClassName` with `import somefolder2.ClassName`, where `somefolder2` is a folder within `ProjectC` and `somefolder2/ClassName` is the newer version of `ClassName` that I want to be used within by 50 `PackageA` classes.

How do I get rid of the deprecated `ProjectB/somefolder/ClassName` in favour of the new `ProjectC/somefolder2/ClassName` in every class in `ProjectA`?

Answer (score 0):

- Search
- File
- enter "import somefolder" in the "Containing text" field
- enter "*.java" in the "File name patterns" field
- click Replace...
- enter "import somefolder2"
- click OK.